# How can I prove the variance of geometric Brownian motion without using stochastic calculus?

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

I need to prove the variance of the geometric Brownian motion, but I'm stuck, since I managed to determine the expectation in this way

Let be
$$G_t=G_0e^{\mu t+\sigma W(t)}$$
Then the mean is
$$E[G_t]=E[G_0e^{\mu t+\sigma W(t)}]$$
$$=G_0e^{\mu t}E[e^{\sigma W(t)}]$$
Where $E[e^{\sigma W(t)}]$
$$E[e^{\sigma x}]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\sigma x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t}e^{-\frac{(x-\sigma t)^2}{2t}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}dx$$
$$=e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t}$$
Therefore
$$E[G_t]=G_0e^{(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t}$$

But when I try
$$Var(G_t)=E[G_t^2]-[E[G_t]]^2$$
I don't know how to compute $E[G_t^2]$

OK, I've tried this

$$E[G_t^2]=E[G_0^2e^{2X(t)}]=G_0^2E[e^{2(\mu t+\sigma W(t))}]=G_0^2e^{2\mu t}E[e^{2\sigma W(t)}]$$

Where $E[e^{2\sigma W(t)}]$
$$E[e^{2\sigma W(t)}]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{2\sigma x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}dx$$
$$$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{2\sigma^2t}e^{-\frac{(x-2\sigma t)^2}{2t}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}dx$$
$$=e^{2\sigma^2t}$$

Then
$$E[G_t^2]=G_0^2e^{2\mu t}e^{2\sigma^2 t}=G_0^2e^{2t(\mu +\sigma^2)}$$
$$\therefore Var[G_t]=G_0^2e^{2t(\mu +\sigma^2)}-G_0^2e^{2(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t}$$

Comment: How far do you get?

Comment: Looks OK. Was going to give the Hint: $G^2_t=G_0^2e^{2\mu+2\sigma W(t)}$. Write this exponential as $e^{aW(t)-\frac{a^2t}{2}+b}$.