# Determine the covariance of geometric Brownian motion without using stochastic calculus.

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, covariance

I've tried this
$$Cov(Gt,Gs)=E[G_tG_s]-E[G_t]E[G_s]$$
For the term $E[G_tG_s]$
$$E[G_tG_s]=E[G(t)(G(s)-G(t)+G(t))]$$
$$=E[G(t)G(s-t)]+E[G(t)^2]$$
$$=E[G(t)]E[G(s-t)]+E[G(t)^2]$$
I know that [Mean and second moment of $G_t$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463698/how-can-i-prove-the-variance-of-geometric-brownian-motion-without-using-stochast?noredirect=1#comment9352724_4463698)
$$E[G(t)]=G_0e^{(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t}$$
$$E[G_t^2]=G_0^2e^{2t(\mu+\sigma^2)}$$
I just need to calculate $E[G(s-t)]$
$$E[G(s-t)]=G_0E[e^{\mu(s-t)+\sigma W(s-t)}]$$
$$=G_0e^{\mu(s-t)}E[e^{\sigma W(s-t)}]$$
Where $E[e^{\sigma W(s-t)}]$
$$E[e^{\sigma W(s-t)}]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\sigma x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (s-t)}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(s-t)}}dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(s-t)}e^{-\frac{(x-\sigma (s-t))^2}{2(s-t)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (s-t)}}dx$$
$$=e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(s-t)}$$
Then
$$E[G(s-t)]=G_0e^{\mu(s-t)}e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(s-t)}$$
$$=G_0e^{(s-t)(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})}$$
And so the term
$$E[G_tG_s]=G_0e^{(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t}G_0e^{(s-t)(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})}+G_0^2e^{2t(\mu+\sigma^2)}$$
$$=G_0^2e^{(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})s}+G_0^2e^{2t(\mu+\sigma^2)}$$
Finally
$$Cov(G_t,G_s)=G_0^2e^{(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})s}+G_0^2e^{2t(\mu+\sigma^2)}-G_0^2e^{(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(t+s)}$$